# When it seems a Pope has heretical beliefs, who determines whether those beliefs are Magisterial?

Tags: catholicism, papacy

I know that even some Catholics think that certains Popes held personal heresies (were material heretics). For example Honorius I believed that Jesus had only one will, the heresy of monothelitism.

I understand that a Pope might be a heretic, but to preserve the believed infallibility of his office he can't impose those beliefs *ex cathedra*—i.e., using the full weight of his office—onto the Church.

Who has the authority to judge which statements issued by the Pope are infallible?

Note: This [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/when-does-the-pope-speak-ex-cathedra) seems to address what the "criteria" used are, but I am asking: Who uses these criteria to decide the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Whether valid popes have been heretics

It isn't necessarily true that Pope Honorius I was a heretic. St. Robert Cardinal Bellarmine, the great doctor of the papacy, defended several popes, including Pope Honorius I, against accusations of heresy in his work that is translated into English as [*Papal Error?: A Defense of Popes said to have Erred in Fatih*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5524) (ch. 4 is on Pope Honorius I). Among the seven accusations against Pope Honorius I that St. Robert's refutes are the [the accusations that Dialogist quotes below](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50470/1787).

St. Robert also treats the question of whether a Pope can be a heretic in  [*De Romano Pontifice*, lib. II, cap. 30](http://www.strobertbellarmine.net/bellarm.htm) ([*On the Roman Pontiff*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5349)). He argues that a pope cannot be a heretic; if he is, he, like St. Francis de Sales wrote in his [*Catholic Controversy* p. 306](http://www.archive.org/details/catholiccontrove00sain),

> falls *ipso facto* from his dignity and out of the Church, and the Church must either deprive him, or, as some say, declare him deprived, of his Apostolic See, and must say as S. Peter did: *Let another take his bishopric*.*
> <sup>*Acts i.</sup>

## Who can judge a pope's validity?

As I mentioned in [my answer to your other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50479/1787), only a valid Pope is the supreme judge:

> [Can.  1442](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50470/1787) The Roman Pontiff is the supreme judge for the entire Catholic world; he renders judicial decisions personally, through the ordinary tribunals of the Apostolic See, or through judges he has delegated.

This law is based upon the infallible dogma of papal primacy which, *pace* [Dialogist's answer above](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50470/1787), has been true since the time Christ instituted the Papacy (Matt. 16:16-19), founding it on the rock of St. Peter himself, the first Pope. As the First Vatican Council ([*Pastor æternus* ch. 4 "Of the Institution of the Apostolic Primacy in blessed Peter"](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.ii.i.html#v.ii.i-p30.9)), united with the Pope, infallibly declared:

> We therefore teach and declare that, according to the testimony of the Gospel, the primacy of jurisdiction over the universal Church of God was immediately and directly promised and given to blessed Peter the Apostle by Christ the Lord. For it was to Simon alone, to whom he had already said: "Thou shalt be called Cephas," [John i. 42.] that the Lord after the confession made by him, saying: 'Thou art the Christ, the Son of the living God,' addressed these solemn words: 'Blessed art thou, Simon Bar-Jona, because flesh and blood have not revealed it to thee, but my Father who is in heaven.
>
> And I say to thee that thou art Peter; and upon this rock I will build my Church, and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it. And I will give to thee the keys of the kingdom of heaven. And whatsoever thou shalt bind on earth, it shall be bound also in heaven; and whatsoever thou shalt loose on earth, it shall be loosed also in heaven.' [Matt. xvi. 16-19.] And it was upon Simon alone that Jesus after his resurrection bestowed the jurisdiction of chief pastor and ruler over all his fold in the words: 'Feed my lambs; feed my sheep.' [John xxi. 15-17.] At open variance with this clear doctrine of Holy Scripture as it has been ever understood by the Catholic Church are the perverse opinions of those who, while they distort the form of government established by Christ the Lord in his Church, deny that Peter in his single person, preferably to all the other Apostles, whether taken separately or together, was endowed by Christ with a true and proper primacy of jurisdiction; or of those who assert that the same primacy was not bestowed immediately and directly upon blessed Peter himself, but upon the Church, and through the Church on Peter as her minister.
>
> If any one, therefore, shall say that blessed Peter the Apostle was not appointed the Prince of all the Apostles and the visible Head of the whole Church Militant; or that the same directly and immediately received from the same our Lord Jesus Christ a primacy of honor only, and not of true and proper jurisdiction: let him be anathema.

## Any Catholic can and must recognize and refuse to follow an antipope.

However, any Catholic who recognizes an antipope as an antipope must refuse to follow him. St. Paul says twice in Galatian 1:8-9:

> But although we, or an Angel from heaven, evangelize to you beside that which we have evangelized to you, be he anathema.
>
> As we have said before, so now I say again, If any evangelize to you beside that which we have evangelized to you, be he anathema.

Notice, St. Paul says *anyone*, which certainly includes those who appear to be popes (antipopes).

Comment: Oh I was not expecting someone to defend Honorius. And I now see this is somewhat controversial within the Catholic church history. So basically you are saying Honorius was not a heretic, the council was in error and only a valid Pope can declare this to be so. Is my understanding of your argument correct?

Comment: @Mike "_only a valid Pope can declare this to be so_" Yes, only a pope can make a final judgment of whether Pope Honorius was a heretic or not. As Pope Pius XII writes in his 1950 encyclical [_Humani Generis_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_12081950_humani-generis.html): "if the Supreme Pontiffs in their official documents purposely pass judgment on a matter up to that time under dispute, it is obvious that that matter, according to the mind and will of the Pontiffs, cannot be any longer considered a question open to discussion among theologians."

Comment: @Mike A present or future pope could certainly settle this question by "pass[ing] judgment on…[this] matter…under dispute", i.e., on the question of whether a valid Pope remains Pope even if he falls into heresy.

Comment: Christ did not found the Church on the person of Peter.  This is a common distortion of Scripture.  Please see Augustines comentary on 1 John and Chrysostom's commentary on Matthew 16:18.  Both are Doctors of the Roman Catholic Church and both maintain that the Lord built His Church not upon the person of Peter, but rather upon his confession of faith ("You are the Christ, the Son of the Living of God").  The documents are available on newadvent.com, a Roman Catholic website.

Comment: @dialogist I would like to see the exact references, preferably with summary quotes. That would be more appropriate as the answer to another question, if that works. Otherwise, perhaps we should discuss this further in chat, lest we appear argumentative.

Comment: @disciple It seems very related to Mike's question here since if the Church is built "on the faith of his confession," as St. John Chrysostom says in his [Homily 54 on Matthew](http://newadvent.com/fathers/200154.htm), and not on St. Peter himself, it would seem clearer that if a successor of St. Peter ceases to confess the faith (if he apostatizes), he ceases being pope.

Comment: @Dialogist St. Robert ([_On the Roman Pontiff_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5349) ch. 11): «Chrysostom, explaining this passage in Matthew, says: “He constituted him pastor of the Church.” [_In Matth. Hom._ 55.] And below that: “The Father put Jeremiah in charge of one nation, while Christ put Peter in charge of the whole world.” Ambrose says: “The rock is called Peter just as an immovable boulder that it should contain the unified structure of the whole Christian work.” [_Serm._ 47.]…

Comment: @Dialogist «… St. Gregory says: “It is proven to everyone who knows the Gospel that care of the whole Church was consigned to St. Peter, prince of all apostles by the Lord’s voice. By all means it was said to him: 'You are Peter, and upon this rock I will build my Church.’” [Bk. 4, ep. 32.]»

Answer (score 2):

Pope Honorius I served from 625 to 638 when the Church was still undivided.  At that time there was no doctrine within the Church of Papal infallibility and the Pope's place with respect to the other Patriarchs was understood to be first in honor, but he had no authority over any bishop outside the jurisdiction of the Roman See. These things were innovations which led to or occurred sometime after the See of Rome separated mutually from the other four ancient Sees (Constantinople, Alexandria, Antioch, Jerusalem) in the 11th century.

(I would hasten to add that although the Pope had no jurisdiction outside of the Roman See, Patriarchs and the faithful would frequently appeal outside their Patriarchate for spiritual guidance and support when problems appeared from within.  This was the case, for example, during the iconoclast heresy when Church Fathers such as Germanus and John of Damascus appealed for support from Pope Gregory II against Emperor Leo the Isaurian.  The case of Honorius shows that the system also worked in the opposite direction:  the faithful of Rome had recourse to the eastern Patriarchs.)

Pope Honorius was condemned and anathematized by the council of bishops which met during the Sixth Ecumenical Council at Constantinople in 680-681.  His sentence reads:

> The holy council said: After we had reconsidered, according to our
>   promise which we had made to your highness, the doctrinal letters of
>   Sergius, at one time patriarch of this royal god-protected city to
>   Cyrus, who was then bishop of Phasis and to Honorius some time Pope of
>   Old Rome, as well as the letter of the latter to the same Sergius, we
>   find that these documents are quite foreign to the apostolic dogmas,
>   to the declarations of the holy Councils, and to all the accepted
>   Fathers, and that they follow the false teachings of the heretics;
>   therefore we entirely reject them, and execrate them as hurtful to the
>   soul. But the names of those men whose doctrines we execrate must also
>   be thrust forth from the holy Church of God

The declaration which anathematized Honorius:

> Many years to the Emperor! Many years to Constantine, our great
>   Emperor! Many years to the Orthodox King! Many years to our Emperor
>   that maketh peace! Many years to Constantine, a second Martian! Many
>   years to Constantine, a new Theodosius! Many years to Constantine, a
>   new Justinian! Many years to the keeper of the orthodox faith! O Lord
>   preserve the foundation of the Churches! O Lord preserve the keeper of
>   the faith! 
>  Many years to Agatho, Pope of Rome! Many years to
>   George, Patriarch of Constantinople! Many years to Theophanus,
>   Patriarch of Antioch! Many years to the orthodox council! Many years
>   to the orthodox Senate! 
>  To Theodore of Pharan, the heretic,
>   anathema!
>   To Sergius, the heretic, anathema!
>   To Cyrus, the
>   heretic, anathema!
>   To Honorius, the heretic, anathema!
>   To
>   Pyrthus, the heretic, anathema!
>  To Paul
>  To Peter
>  To
>   Macarius
>  To Stephen
>  To Polychronius
>  To Apergius of Perga
>   the heretic, anathema!
>  
>  To all heretics, anathema! To all who
>   side with heretics, anathema! 
>  May the faith of the Christians
>   increase, and long years to the orthodox and Ecumenical Council!

These documents can be found in the English translations available of the Acts and Canons of the Ecumenical Councils (e.g. [CCEL](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf214.xiii.viii.html))

Comment: Very interesting bit of history. I may however have to accept a Catholic apologetic answer, if it can be shows that there is some formula to determine that Honorius was infallible while being a heretic and anathamized. As bizarre as that sounds, I am expecting this to be the current RC view as this Pope is not considered an anti-Pope today. But wow, great info!

Comment: I should have added that Pope Honorius was not the only Patriarch that the Council anathematized.   The "Cyrus" mentioned in had been the Patriarch of Alexandria and "Paul" was Paul II, who had been Patriarch of Constantinople.   In my opinion, one of the advantages to the organization of the Church was its very division into independent Sees.  It seems to have put a system of "checks and balances" in place.  This system still exists today in the Orthodox Church, but it frustrates and puzzles some that no on seems to be "in charge".

Comment: Regarding the accusation that Pope Honorius I was a monothelite, see [ch. 4 of St. Robert Bellarmine's defense against accusations that popes have erred in faith](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5524); he discusses the accusations you quote here.

Comment: Also, it is not Catholic to say that "the Pope had no jurisdiction outside of the Roman See." See the First Vatican Council quote in my answer below regarding how papal primacy existed from the very moment described in Matt. 16:16-19.

Comment: "_when the Church was still undivided_": The [Mystical Body of Christ](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html) can never be divided. It is one of the four marks of the Church that she is **one**, holy, Catholic, and apostolic; cf. St. Robert Bellarmine's [_On the Marks of the Church_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5520).

Comment: Robert Bellarmie has no canonical standing as a saint in the Orthodox Church, and even if he did that would not convey any more or less truth to whatever he might claim.   But neither my opinions nor his are relevant.  The rule (canon) of the Church against the heresies during the 1st millennium was the Ecumenical Council.  Are you maintaining that the anathemas imposed by the Sixth Ecumenical Council were not valid?

Comment: You are absolutely correct about the true Church not being able to be divided.  I lapsed into euphemism.  In the view of the Eastern Orthodox Church, the See of Rome is currently outside the Church.

Comment: @Geremia The problem is that Pope Leo oversaw the above council and made the sentence on Honorius himself. So either Honorius was wrong or Leo was, but someone was wrong. Officially. But I think that's the real point in this question. Where's the line between infallible judgments and not? Was Leo's condemnation of Honorius intended to be understood as infallible?

Comment: @Joshua Here's what St. Robert thought: "The same men who corrupted the Sixth Council also corrupted the epistle of Leo. If that epistle were to be thought of as some part of the Council, it is fashioned with that Council. Or else Leo followed the judgment of the legates of Agatho, lest he would disturb a business that was already settled. But **we are not held** anymore **to follow** one Leo than so many other **Popes, especially in a question of fact, which does not pertain to the faith**."

Comment: Note that Honorius was not condemned by Pope Leo.  He was condemned by the Council.

Comment: @Dialogist "_the anathemas imposed by the Sixth Ecumenical Council were not valid?_"  St. Robert advances a few theories: (1) "in the Sixth Council itself, act 12 and 14, many corruptions were discovered made by heretics in the Fifth Council. And Pope Leo sought from the Greeks why they had corrupted his epistle to Flavian even though he was still living? Pope Gregory asserted that at Constantinople they had corrupted the Council of Chalcedon, and he suspected the same about Ephesus. And he adds, the codices of the Romans by far had greater veracity than those of the Greeks".

Comment: @Dialogist (2) "the Fathers of the Sixth Council condemned Honorius but from false information, and hence erred in that judgment. Although a legitimate general Council could not err in defining dogmas of faith (and the Sixth Council did not), still it could err in questions of fact."

Comment: @Geremia we [can chat more](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30725214#30725214) if you like. I'm not even sure who St Robert is

Comment: @Joshua [St. Robert Bellarmine](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02411d.htm) (1542-1621) is a Doctor of the Church; he wrote against Luther and Calvin. Read his full defense of Pope Honorius I in ch. 4 of [_Papal Error?: A Defense of Popes said to have Erred in Fatih_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5524); it's what I quoted from above.