# Earliest mention of Catholic Church as Antichrist?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, antichrist

What is the earliest recorded instance of the popes being identified as the Antichrist or the Whore of Babylon, and who was the figure responsible for making this claim? Additionally, how did this interpretation of Catholicism develop over time, and what are some of the main arguments used to support or refute it within different Christian traditions?

Comment: Do you mean the earliest mention of a pope being Antichrist?

Comment: [Antichrist is a person](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/73483/1787) (not an institution).